What is the difference between complex sine and cosine in gnuradio?
Today I am trying to learn gnuradio frequency shifting and I find out that if signal source, being complex, is changed from cosine(as used in the tutorial) to sine, the frequency shift of the low pass filter is the same.
I then read the documentation of the signal source generator here and find out that the two signals are actually the same. $$\cos(2\pi\text{ft}) = \sin(2\pi\text{ft}) = e^{i2\pi\text{ft}}$$,
where $e^{i2\pi\text{ft}} = \cos(2\pi\text{ft}) +\text{i}\sin(2\pi \text{ft})$ and $ t = \frac{n}{\text{sample rate}}$.
Isn't it that sine lags cosine by a radian of $\frac{\pi}{2}$, and such that sine is given by $e^{i(2\pi\text{ft}-\frac{\pi}{2})}$ ?

again, and I want to stress that: The equation you put there is both wrong (and you correctly identified that), and it's also not implied in the GNU Radio documentation. Please don't convert "when you configure the sine source block to be complex-valued, it gives the same output as the cosine block configured to be complex-valued" with "these two very different trigonometric functions are identical". That wasn't said anywhere, and while GNU Radio's choice of naming there is bad, it doesn't imply that.

to answer your titular question,

What is the difference between complex sine and cosine in gnuradio?

As you notice, none.

Dear future reader, Bodhisattva is right! Note that

$\cos(2\pi\text{ft}) = \sin(2\pi\text{ft}) = e^{i2\pi\text{ft}}$

is simply wrong (but it's also not what the documentation says).

that sine lags cosine by a radian of π/2

You're absolutely right.
But the original author of that block took some freedom, and implemented both to be identical for the complex output case only.
Was that a choice that I'd agree with? No. But, it happened maybe around 20 years ago, and as a software project, you make a lot of users unhappy when you break a lot of existing flow graphs to correct that mistake.
If you need to shift the phase of a complex sine signal by $\frac\pi2$, just put that into the the Initial Phase field.

Hello Marcus thanks for your details answer again! Just want to note that in the documentation, the complex sine and cosine is not in exponential form but in complex form, i.e. $$\sin = \cos = \text{A}(\cos(2\pi \text{ft})+i\sin(2\pi\text{ft}))+\text{offset}$$

I want to stress that the documentation does nowhere use the equality sign between sin and cos! That's you interpreting the statement of "in these two different parametrizations, this block produces the same output" as "sine and cosine are the same", and I think that's a thing you should avoid doing. The textual name of an option is a different thing than the mathetical concept of a trigonometric function :) It's fair to say "in the terminology of GNU Radio's Signal Source block, the "complex-valued sine" and the "complex-valued cosine" are identical", but I wouldn't use "sin=cos" ,

as, again, that's not what is written in the documentation, and it's clearly not the case even for the SIgnal Source itself; the real-valued sine and cosine are different.
